# Drawing a linkage or a path between two lines using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing

I am trying to draw a path between 2 lines like the following one.

[image: wanted graph]

I used the following code to do that

```
        Pen usedpen= new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        //Point[] p = {
        //    new Point(518,10),
        //    new Point(518,20),
        //    new Point(518-85,15)
        //};
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddLine(new Point(518, 10), new Point(433, 10));
        path.AddLine(new Point(518, 40), new Point(433, 40));
        path.AddLine(new Point(433,10), new Point(433,40));
        //usedpen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(usedpen, path);
```

But after use this code the following graphic is drawn:

[image: Result]

Any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using as a canvas ?

Comment: i do not use a canvas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh you're using the onPaint event, so the problem is You're drawing a path which means the Point will go from end of the first line to the starting of the next line.

After the first line

`path.AddLine(new Point(518, 10), new Point(433, 10));`

Now the Point is at (433, 10)

Now the next line Says go from (518, 40) to (433, 40)

now what's actually happening is there's a line being drawn from (433, 10) to (518, 40) because it's a path it continue drawing.

```
 GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
 path.StartFigure();
 path.AddLine(new Point(518, 10), new Point(433, 10));
 path.AddLine(new Point(433, 10), new Point(433, 40));
 path.AddLine(new Point(433, 40), new Point(518, 40));
 usedpen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
```

Comment: Sorry if the explanation is messy

Comment: No, i understand your explanation and it works , Thanks bro

Answer (score 3):

By default whenever you add a figure, say a Line to GraphicPath its starting point will be connected to the end point of the last figure. Therefore order matters!

The way to prevent this is it to use [`StartFigure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.startfigure(v=vs.110).aspx) whenever you want to draw **unconnected** lines:

> Starts a new figure without closing the current figure. All subsequent
>   points added to the path are added to this new figure.

```
    Pen usedpen= new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    //Point[] p = {
    //    new Point(518,10),
    //    new Point(518,20),
    //    new Point(518-85,15)
    //};
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

    path.StartFigure();
    path.AddLine(new Point(518, 10), new Point(433, 10));
    path.StartFigure();   // <---
    path.AddLine(new Point(518, 40), new Point(433, 40));
    path.StartFigure();   // <---
    path.AddLine(new Point(433,10), new Point(433,40));
    //usedpen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Round;
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(usedpen, path);
```

[image]

Of course your problem basically was the wrong **order** or drawing lines, so the other answer is correct.

The recommended way to draw connected lines, btw, is to use `AddLines` because it will avoid problems at the line joints, caps or miters..

Answer (score 1):

A similar method, using [GraphicsPath.AddLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addlines(v=vs.110).aspx) (which also Disposes the object created).

[GraphicsPath.StartFigure()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.startfigure(v=vs.110).aspx) is not used, since it's the only figure drawn. When more points are added to the GraphicsPath, `.StartFigure()` will create a new subpath, without linking the pre-existing ones.

Subpaths can be parsed, for testing the type of shapes they contain, using the [GraphicsPathIterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspathiterator(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
{
    Point[] points = new Point[] {
        new Point(518, 10), new Point(433, 10),
        new Point(433, 40), new Point(433, 40),
        new Point(433, 40), new Point(518, 40)
    };

    path.AddLines(points);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), path);

    //Add a new figure
    path.StartFigure();
    path.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(450, 40, 50, 50));
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), path);
};
```